# Drive SDK Get Folder Size

Tags: google-drive-api

I am using 'quotaBytedUsed' property while getting [Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files) using an authorized get request - [Files.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list).

I am converting the long value obtained to file size in KB/MB/Gb as appropriate.

However, size of all folders obtained is 1 KB. This value doesn't reflect the sum total of sizes of all content in the folder.

How can I get the this sum ( if possible without any extra request to server )?

Code used for converting 'quotaBytesUsed' to file size is

```
private string[] SizeSuffixes = new[] { "B", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB" };

private string SizeConvert(long? fileSize)
    {
        if (!fileSize.HasValue)
            return "";

        var size = fileSize.Value;

        if (size <= 1024)
        {
            return "1 KB";
        }

        var suffixIndex = 0;

        while (size > 1024)
        {
            size = size / 1024;

            suffixIndex++;
        }

        return size.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat) + " " + SizeSuffixes[suffixIndex];
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting the size of the folder object, not its contents.
The api doesnt support getting a folder content's size.

Given that the same file/folder can be in multiple folders, I doubt it will ever be supported.

You need to recursively calculate it, using appengine task queues for example.

Comment: Multiple parents are no longer allowed in google drive.