# Size of the folder in Google Drive

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-drive-api

I've browsed the documentation & searched in code. Is there any way to get the size of the folder and it's contents in Google Drive SDK for iOS?

The `GTLDriveFile` has a property `fileSize`, but it's `0` for folders. The `properties` property is `nil`. Where can I look for it?

Maybe I should compose a new query for it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

@Vive, based on this documentation [**Working with Folders**](https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/devguide/folders#top_of_page),

> **Folders are specialized files with metadata but no content.** There are a number of additional operations that can be used on folders to query and manage child entries.

As stated from this [previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19362444/drive-sdk-get-folder-size), "You are getting the size of the folder object, not its contents. The api doesn't support getting a folder content's size. You need to recursively calculate it, using appengine task queues for example."

I hope this helps you create a workaround the query you need.

Comment: Well, I was afraid there's not other solution, was hoping opposite. Poor user experience... Using Google API framework is a pain comparing to other frameworks. They should take a look into e.g. Shinobi team frameworks.